# how can fetch all emails

Tags: php, contextio

I use contextio for fetch all email of my account but I haven't fetch any email

this is code:

```
$args = array('label' => 'Primary','folder' => 'Inbox');
    $r = $contextio->listMessages('5a7364c56d5d992d945d54c3', $args);
    if ($r !== false) {
        foreach ($r->getData() as $message) {
            echo "Subject: ".$message['subject']."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        var_dump($r);
    }
```

output is false (in case else)

Comment: in `else {` put `print_r($contextio->getLastResponse());` and tell the response

Comment: @TamilSelvanC, output is "Primary not found" but I do not understand label when i get messages !!

Comment: how looks like print_r($r) before the if ?

Comment: @romph , i look false

Comment: @romph , Attempted to call an undefined method named "listMessagesBySourceAndFolder" of class "ContextIO".

Comment: i think you use https://github.com/contextio/PHP-Lite-ContextIO


`

$r = $contextio->listEmailAccounts(USER_ID);
print_r($r->getData());`

First check the label is exist there

Comment: @TamilSelvanC , this screenshot of output
https://imgur.com/uCK3dyy

Comment: `$params = array('label'=>"thelabelofthescreen");
$r = $contextio->listEmailAccountFolders(USER_ID, $params);
print_r($r);` if you see the folder inbox you just need to remplace 'primary'

Comment: @romph , I use gmail .. folder Inbox and label !!

Comment: any help please for explication what is label !!

Comment: when i launch function .. in logs in site contextio i have this line : https://imgur.com/a/cpFZ7